# Query to exclude negating value-pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server

Create Table #Temp(Number Varchar(20), Category Varchar(20))

```
Insert Into #Temp 
Select '123', '-A'
Union all
Select '123', 'A'
Union all
Select '123', 'A'
Union all
Select '123','B'
Union all
Select '123','-B' 

Select * From  #temp  

result set
---------------------------
Number  Category
123      -A
123       A
123       A
123       B
123      -B
123       C
123      -C
123      -C
---------------------------
```

From the above set of the data I need to query showing only one A when there are 2 -A and one A.

All i need is to have an output that cancels the -A and A where ever necessary, from the above example,

the query should return the below only

```
result set
---------------------------
Number  Category 
123      A 
123     -C
---------------------------
```

Comment: Please fix your sample data, where does `-C` come from, what happened to 
 `B` and `-B`? Am I right to assume you want to keep the one that occurs most often?

Comment: If I'm understanding, you want the letter values to cancel each other out? Like if they were integers, the "sums" of A would be 1, B would be 0 and C would be -1? And if B=0 it's not shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by replace(category, '-', ''), seqnum) as cnt_sc
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by category order by category) as seqnum
            from temp t
           ) t
     ) t
where cnt_sc = 1;
```

For a given category this enumerates the rows.  It then counts the number for each enumeration, taking the "-" into account.  It returns the rows that have only one enumeration -- they have no matches.

Note:  This assumes that `category` has no hyphens except at the beginning.

EDIT:

If you know that there will be at most one such row, you can do:

```
select number,
       (case when count(*) > sum(case when category like '-%' then 1 else 0)
             then '-' + replace(category, '-', '')
             else replace(category, '-', '')
        end)
from t
group by number, replace(category, '-', '')
having count(*) <> 2 * sum(case when category like '-%' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: this works. Thanks for your quick reply. I really appreciate it. After seeing the code I felt so dumb that I couldn't able to figure this out before. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution but perhaps someone else has a more elegant approach:

```
WITH cte as(
            SELECT 
                SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(Category, 1) = '-' 
                         THEN -1
                         ELSE 1 
                         END) as summed
                , Right(Category,1) AS nuCat
            FROM #Temp
            GROUP BY Number, RIGHT(Category, 1)
            )

SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(summed) > 0 
             THEN nuCat
             ELSE '-' + nuCat 
             END AS DerivedCategory  
FROM cte
GROUP BY nuCat
HAVING SUM(summed) <> 0
```

Using the CTE to turn the character strings into integers to `SUM` them. Then, when selecting from the CTE, the string is concatenated back with the integer "sign" from the summed values in the CTE.

The result:

```
DerivedCategory
---------------
A
-C
```